# Creating a "Car" class with Accelerate method, and associate Accel and Decel buttons on form with created class

Tags: c#

Taking a C#.Net class and we have been introduced a new concept of using a class with a form. It's an online class and basically the instructor has given us instructions, however they are somewhat unclear, at least to me.  Unfortunately, his responses to students questions are very vague and basically, in a nut shell, told us to figure it out, so I be here. Below is what the instructor gave us.

=========================================================================

UML: Model: String, CurrentSpeed: Decimal, TopSpeed: Decimal, and Accelerate (change speed: Decimal)

Accelerate  adds changeSpeed (which can be positive, negative or 0) to CurrentSpeed. CurrentSpeed can never exceed TopSpeed or be less than 0
e.g. if CurrentSpeed is 10 and dChangeSpeed is -20, CurrentSpeed becomes 0

General Requirements:

- Top Speed combo box is filled with numbers 60, 70, 80 …. 200 
  (at Run time)
- Change Speed combo box is filled with numbers 1, 2, 3 ….200 
  (at Run time)
- User must select from combo box (cannot enter own numbers)

Button Action Requirements:

Accelerate  For same model, increases Current Speed by Change Speed
        For new model, sets Current Speed to Change Speed
        (Current Speed can’t exceed Top Speed)

Decelerate  For same model, decreases Current Speed by Change Speed
        For new model, sets Current Speed to 0
        (Current Speed can’t go below 0)

UML diagram is followed exactly.
Work (calculations, etc) done in the class, not the form.

=========================================================================

Ok, so my question is, should I use a Deceleration method, along with the Accelerate in the class?  I'm assuming that each button (decel, accel) would need its own method in the class.  However I think I'm overly making this complicated, which was the answer to one of my question I asked my instructor.  I guess I'm totally stumped as to how to reference the class, specifically the Accelerate with the form.

So far, this is what I came up with, which I know is mostly wrong, however this is a beginners class from what I'm told and the support form the instructor is not there other than relying on a chapter about classes.

```
public class Car
{
    // Backing Fields (Instance Variables)
    private string _model;
    private int _currentSpeed;
    private int _topSpeed;

    public int SpeedResult;

    // Set Parameters
    public Car()
    {
        this.Model = "";
        this.CurrentSpeed = 0;
        this.TopSpeed = 0;
    }

    // Constructor
    public Car(string Model, int CurrentSpeed, int TopSpeed)
    {
        _model = Model;
        _currentSpeed = CurrentSpeed;
        _topSpeed = TopSpeed;
    }

    // Model Property
    public string Model
    {
        get { return _model; }
        set { _model = value; }
    }

    // Current Speed Property
    public int CurrentSpeed
    {
        get { return _currentSpeed; }
        set { _currentSpeed = value; }
    }

    // Top Speed Property
    public int TopSpeed
    {
        get { return _topSpeed; }
        set { _topSpeed = value; }
    }

    // Methods
    public int Accelerate()
    {

            SpeedResult = (TopSpeed + CurrentSpeed);  
            return SpeedResult;
    }

    //
    public void clear()
    {
        Model = "";
        CurrentSpeed = 0;
        TopSpeed = 0;
    }
}
```

Form:

```
public partial class carSpeedForm : Form
{
    private Car _myCar;
    private int SpeedResult;

    public carSpeedForm()
    {
        _myCar = new Car();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void carSpeedForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //  Loads Amount ComboBox with values from 60 to 200 in increments of 10
        for (int i = 60; i <= 200; i += 10)
            topSpeedComboBox.Items.Add(i);
        //  Loads Amount ComboBox with values from 1 to 200 in increments of 1
        for (int i = 1; i <= 200; i += 1)
            changeSpeedComboBox.Items.Add(i); 
    }

    private void GetCarData()
    {
        try
        {
            _myCar.Model = carModelTextBox.Text;
            _myCar.TopSpeed = int.Parse(topSpeedComboBox.Text);
            _myCar.CurrentSpeed = int.Parse(changeSpeedComboBox.Text);
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Concat("Please enter a valid model and speed(s) for vehicle.","\r\n"));
        }
    }

    private void accelButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetCarData();
        speedResultLabel.Text = SpeedResult.ToString("n1");
        carResultLabel.Text = String.Format("Your car is a new car.");
    }

    private void decelButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetCarData();
        speedResultLabel.Text = SpeedResult.ToString("n1");
        carResultLabel.Text = String.Format("Your car is a new car.");
    }

    private void clearButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Clear textbox, combobox, labels
        carModelTextBox.Clear();
        carModelTextBox.Focus();
        topSpeedComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
        changeSpeedComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
        speedResultLabel.Text = "";
        carResultLabel.Text = "";
    }

    private void exitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Close application
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not only is your code not “mostly wrong”, I’d even call it mostly right. It is not clear exactly what you are asking, or what “how to reference the class” means.
The instructor is right to tell you to “to figure it out”, and we can’t do your assignment for you. If you have working code you want people to review, post it on the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site.

However, there are a few [code smells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) that, in my experience, will lead to problems in the future:

```
// Backing Fields (Instance Variables)
```

Do not comment programming terms; they contribute nothing and soon go out of sync with the code. Only comment things that cannot be expressed in the programming language.

```
private string _model;

// Model Property
public string Model
{
    get { return _model; }
    set { _model = value; }
}
```

That’s about the most verbose way possible to define a property. Defining separate backing fields only encourages people to use the backing field instead of the property. Moreover, making it `public` makes any consumer of the class able to change the property at any time. Sometimes you need those things, but you should not allow them unless you absolutely need them. Also, vague names like “Model” are hard to understand, especially if other classes use them. A better definition would be:

```
public string ModelName { get; private set; }
```

­

```
public int SpeedResult;
```

What is this? It’s not in your UML, and is never used for anything. Moreover, it’s `public` so anything can change it to anything; it’s totally useless, get rid of it.

```
// Set Parameters
public Car()
{
    this.Model = "";
    this.CurrentSpeed = 0;
    this.TopSpeed = 0;
}
```

And then in your form constructor:

```
    _myCar = new Car();
```

This is worse than useless; you’re creating instances that contain no data, and every field is public so anything can change your data to anything. C# gives you the ability to enforce that your instances only contain valid data. Use them, and only create an instance when you know its data. You should have only one `Car` constructor like this:

```
public Car(string modelName, float topSpeed)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(modelName)) throw new ArgumentNullException("modelName");
    ModelName = modelName;
    TopSpeed = topSpeed;
}
```

I assume `CurrentSpeed` is mutable, so you probably shouldn’t define it in the constructor; it is a candidate for one of those `public` properties I warned you about.

```
public int Accelerate()
{
    SpeedResult = (TopSpeed + CurrentSpeed);  
    return SpeedResult;
}
```

Why would you add `TopSpeed` to `CurrentSpeed`? That can make `SpeedResult` greater than `TopSpeed`. Why are your speeds `int`s? Your description calls them “decimal”, but the C# `decimal` type is for fixed-point values. `float` is a better choice.

Your question says “Accelerate adds changeSpeed ... to CurrentSpeed ... CurrentSpeed can never exceed TopSpeed or be less than 0”. So do that:

```
public void Accelerate(float changeSpeed)
{
    var predictedSpeed = CurrentSpeed + changeSpeed;
    if (predictedSpeed > TopSpeed)
        CurrentSpeed = TopSpeed;
    else if (predictedSpeed < 0)
        CurrentSpeed = 0;
    else
        CurrentSpeed = predictedSpeed;
}
```

­

```
public void clear()
{
    Model = "";
    CurrentSpeed = 0;
    TopSpeed = 0;
}
```

Again, you're allowing anything at all to wreck your data. Don't do that; if you need to create a new car, then create a `new Car`. If you don’t want to display a car, don’t create one.

There are problems with your `carSpeedForm` as well, but I see MGM is addressing those.

Comment: Appreciate the help Arch.  By all means, not asking anyone to do my homework.  In fact, I like the grind so its all good and apologies if this was posted in the wrong session.  Have good night :)

Answer (score 0):

Reading the description you wrote, it looks like you basically have the concept down.  From your form, I assume you will be selecting a car type?  If that is the case, you basically want to define all your model(Car) behavior in a Car class.
For example, as you have already done, you would want to define accessors for the selected cars data and the Accelerate and Decelerate methods.  That way inside you view(carSpeedForm) you can call the perspective method when the corresponding button is pressed.  I.E. if the user presses the Accelerate button on the form, you would call the Accelerate method of the instance of Car.  Hope that helps. You're not far off.

You should use the button and input controls to store the data in your_myCar instances. For Example

```
public partial class CarForm : Form
{
    private Car theCar;
    private bool modelChanged;
    public CarForm()
    {
        theCar = new Car();
        InitializeComponent();
        loadChangeSpeed_cb();
        loadTopSpeed_cb();
        modelChanged = false;
    }

    private void loadChangeSpeed_cb()
    {
        for (decimal i = 1; i <= 200; i++)
        {
            changeSpeed_cb.Items.Add(i);
        }
    }

    private void loadTopSpeed_cb()
    {
        for(decimal i = 60; i <= 200; i+=10)
        {
            topSpeed_cb.Items.Add(i);
        }
    }

    private void accel_b_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(modelChanged)
        {
            theCar.CurrentSpeed = theCar.ChangeSpeed;
            modelChanged = false;
        }
        else
        {
            var si = changeSpeed_cb.SelectedItem;
            if (si == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            theCar.Accelerate((decimal)si);
        }
    }

    private void decel_b_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(modelChanged)
        {
            theCar.CurrentSpeed = 0;
            modelChanged = false;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            var si = changeSpeed_cb.SelectedItem;
            if (si == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            theCar.Accelerate(-(decimal)si);
        }
    }

    private void topSpeed_cb_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var si = topSpeed_cb.SelectedItem;
        if(si == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        theCar.TopSpeed = (decimal)si;
    }

    private void changeSpeed_cb_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var si = changeSpeed_cb.SelectedItem;
        if (si == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        theCar.ChangeSpeed = (decimal)changeSpeed_cb.SelectedItem;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, makes sense, thank you MGM.  Correct, the textbox will allow input of pretty much anything. I believe the object, _myCar, needs to be saved so if you don't change the vehicle model but continue to manipulate speeds, you shouldn't get a "new car" message.  If the model name changes to something else, it should display "This is a new car" message.

Comment: @Heavy I added a quick possible implementation of the view.  I think you can infer my interfaces in the Car object.